# Stocking user visited pages in a serialized array Mysql php : strangely disapearing

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

I stock the page the user has visit in a an serialized array in my database. But when the visitor has visited a few page (~60 or more) the array disapear and it restarts to 0. How could I  fix it ?

Thank you !

My code

```
    if($utilisateur[0]!=null)
{
     $table=unserialize($_SESSION['vue']);
if($table[$_GET["serie"]][$_GET["version"].round($_GET["numero"]/64)]!=null)
{
}
else
{
$table[$_GET["serie"]][$_GET["version"].round($_GET["numero"]/64)]=0;
}

   if($table[$_GET["serie"]][$_GET["version"].round($_GET["numero"]/64)]&pow(2,($_GET["numero"]%64))) 
   {

   }
   else
   {


     $table[$_GET["serie"]][$_GET["version"].round($_GET["numero"]/64)]=$table[$_GET["serie"]][$_GET["version"].round($_GET["numero"]/64)]|pow(2,($_GET["numero"]%64)) ;
     $_SESSION['vue']=serialize($table);
     $req2 = $loginBase->prepare('UPDATE `user` SET vue = ? WHERE utilisateur = ?');
$req2->execute(array($_SESSION['vue'],$utilisateur[0])); 

   }


}
```

I have series (video) and I use binar operation to tell witch episode has been visited but because of int leght I have to change the name if the episode is higher than 64 because int are stock with 64 bites ... 
If I am not clear just ask.
$utilisateur is the array where I stock user data and I have to save info in session too

Comment: Could you add some code?

Comment: here it is thank you to try to answer to me